# Compact and Repair Back-End Database on Shortcut

Tags: ms-access, repair

I created a shortcut which opens and compacts my back-end database and then closes it.

The problem is that if someone has the database open, it throws a warning that a user is using the database. Is there some way to ignore that warning and just close the program?

I'm planning on making this a schedule task on my system to run every night at work, which I assume there will be no one, but just in case someone left their computer on with the database open.

Here is the shortcut I made: (Works perfectly)
"...MSACCESS.EXE" "...MyDB.accdb" /compact "...\Back-Ups\MyDB-Backup.accdb"

I don't know if there's some sort of /ignorewarnings or something like the /compact for the shortcut, which would be great, but if not, is there any other way of doing this with a vbs or bat file?

Answer (score 0):

Variant for host with `MS Access`. Simple `DoCompact.cmd` script file:

```shell
@SET TargetFile=C:\Database1.accdb
@SET ldbFile=C:\Database1.laccdb
@SET AccessExe="c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE"

@IF EXIST %ldbFile% (
@del %ldbFile%
)
@IF NOT EXIST %ldbFile% (
@%AccessExe% %TargetFile% /compact
)
```

Variant for `.mdb` database and without `MS Access` installed. `C:\DoCompact.vbs` script file that should be run on 64 OS by command `%windir%\SysWOW64\cscript C:\DoCompact.vbs`:

```vb
Option Explicit 
Dim logFile 

logFile = "\\srv\Work\compact.log"
Log2File ""
CompactDB "\\srv\Work\Db.mdb", ""
CompactDB "\\srv\Work\DbWithPassword.mdb", "Password"

Sub CompactDB(databaseName, passwd)
    Dim ldbName 
    Dim tempName
    Dim oldName
    Dim objFSO
    Dim Engine
    Dim needToRevert
    Dim trouble
    Dim initialSize
    Dim resultSize
    Dim percent

    logFile = Left(databaseName, InStrRev(databaseName,"\") ) & "\compact.log"
    ldbName = Left(databaseName, Len(databaseName)-3) & "ldb"
    tempName = databaseName & "_compact"
    oldName =  databaseName & "_old"
    initialSize = GetFileSize(databaseName)
    Log2File "Compacting STARTed for " & databaseName & " initial size = " & FormatNumber(initialSize, 0, 0, 0, -1)

    If not(RemoveIfExists(ldbName) And RemoveIfExists(tempName) And (RemoveIfExists(oldName))) Then
        Log2File "Compacting CANCELed because of some file was locked " & databaseName
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

    ' 1 compact to temp
    Set Engine = CreateObject("JRO.JetEngine")
    Engine.CompactDatabase "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & databaseName & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & passwd , _
                           "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & tempName & ";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & passwd

    On Error resume Next
        needToRevert = False
        If objFSO.FileExists(tempName)  Then
            ' 2 rename source to _old
            objFSO.MoveFile databaseName , oldName
            needToRevert = (needToRevert Or (Err.Number <> 0) Or (Not objFSO.FileExists(oldName) ))
        End If

        If Not needToRevert Then
            ' 3 rename temp to source
            objFSO.MoveFile tempName, databaseName
            needToRevert = (needToRevert Or (Err.Number <> 0) Or (Not objFSO.FileExists(databaseName)))
        End If

        If Not needToRevert Then
            ' 4 remove _old
            objFSO.DeleteFile(oldName)
            resultSize = GetFileSize(databaseName)
            percent = resultSize / initialSize 
            Log2File "Compacting done OK for " & databaseName & " result size  = " & FormatNumber(resultSize, 0, 0, 0, -1) & " (" & FormatPercent(percent, 1, -1) & ")"
        Else
            ' RESTORE source from _old if there were errors
            objFSO.MoveFile oldName, databaseName 
            Log2File "Compacting FAILed for " & databaseName
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0 
End Sub

Sub Log2File(message)
    Dim objFSO 
    Dim objFile
    Dim objTS
    Dim messageString
    On Error Resume Next    
        messageString = Now() & " : " & message

        WScript.Echo messageString 

        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        If Not objFSO.FileExists(logFile) Then
            Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(logFile)
            objFile.Close  
        End If
        Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(logFile, 8 ) ' FOR_APPENDING = 8
        objTS.WriteLine messageString
        objTS.Close 
    On Error GoTo 0 
End Sub

Function RemoveIfExists(fileName)
    Dim objFSO

    RemoveIfExists = False
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    If objFSO.FileExists(fileName) Then 
        ' try to remove and if fail - we can't do anything else
        err.Clear
        On Error resume Next
            objFSO.DeleteFile fileName, True
        On Error GoTo 0         
        If (Err.Number <> 0) or (objFSO.FileExists(fileName)) Then
            Log2File "Error while try to remove " & fileName & " file :" & Err.Description 
            Err.Clear
            Exit Function
        End If

    End If
    RemoveIfExists = True
End Function

Function GetFileSize(fileName)
    Dim objFSO
    Dim objFile
    on Error resume next    
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(fileName)
        GetFileSize = objFile.Size 
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: `JRO.JetEngine` is very outdated and generally shouldn't be used, this code certainly requires rewriting to work with accdb files.

Comment: Yes, it is hard coded for `.mdb` and `.ldb`. But `JRO.JetEngine` is used because there is no `Access` installed on host.